# Could a special case of "hardware recommendation" be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, flagging

First time on Meta :)

My question is triggered by: [What is the practical advantage of a higher refresh rate and what should I be looking for when looking for a monitor for FPS gaming?](https://superuser.com/questions/1353222/gaming-monitor-refresh-rate)

This is a hardware recommendation but at least the user made an effort to ask about comparing A to B for the purpose X, and possibility answerable in an authoritative and useful way. But being new I'm not sure I fully understand the house rules.

Please give your opinions about the best approach. Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if it could be reframed as a question about the benefits of high refresh rates. https://superuser.com/questions/990799/will-the-pixel-density-difference-be-visible-between-4k-and-2k-monitors-at-27-s/991823#991823  might be an example on how to do it. Focusing less on specific model and prices would be good too

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Wow... That answer of yours is... Awesome! And timely. I'm considering a new TV/monitor and that gave me some insights and dispelled some myths. That alone "made my day" :) :) :)

Comment: Note that we also have an SE site for [hardwarerecs.se] for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 7):

I've fixed up the post, since, well, I actually think that the 'core' of the question is something useful, and something I don't know anything about.

As a "should I buy A or B?" question... its not great.

As a "What should I be looking at, for this specific application" question I feel it has merit.

I've also commented so OP knows why we just did massive edits to his question and other users know that, well its better than it was before.

Comment: My bad there. I didn't think about that